# How to download a folder from internet to hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a folder on internet and would like to copy it to a hadoop cluster.The files should be downloaded via HTTP protocol. I can create a java application which could iterate through the folder fetch the folder structure and create corresponding structure on HDFS and then download the files one by one to my machine and then upload it to the server. Is there a cleaner way to do such a task without downloading it locally ?

i tried such a command

```
wget -r --no-parent https://example.org/other/2009/2009-01/ -O - |hadoop fs -put -  /user/beni/deleteme3/
```

but it didnt work

Comment: What type of server are the source files located on?  Is it FTP, NFS, HTTP, or something else?

Comment: The files should be transfered via http protocol

Comment: You might try using flume.